# Is it possible that a black hole has a universe in itself?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, universe, singularities, multiverse

Every black hole has a singularity. But the singularity is covered by a thing called 'Event horizon'or ' Schwarzchild Radius'. Our universe is originated from a naked singularity. By naked singularity, I mean that the singularity wasn't covered by the event horizon. Is it possible that a black hole has a universe in itself?

Comment: Note that the [the Big Bang wasn't a naked singularity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/447308/is-the-big-bang-a-naked-spacelike-singularity). It was a *past incomplete spacelike* singularity. A naked singularity is timelike.

Answer (score 0):

I, and I’m sure many many others, have thought about this ever since knowing about black holes.

Both in popular media and in more scientific articles, there’s plenty of viewpoints/interpretations along these lines

https://www.insidescience.org/news/every-black-hole-contains-new-universe

https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/0004-637X/832/2/96

Personally, I think if black holes can somehow be married with the ideas of quantum gravity/information one day, then recursive black holes (since the ‘universes’ inside them might also contain them) might prove to be impossible and that would somewhat contradict the recursive universe theories.

I also dread the day someone had to define exactly what a universe “U” would mean, from a definition point of view..