# Moving singularities

Tags: astrophysics, singularities

I am aware that black holes can move through space-time. Is there a way to move a naked gravitational singularity artificially?
Sorry if this is a little stupid, trying to figure out the feasibility of singularity propulsion.

Comment: Naked singularities probably don't exist. We hope. ;) See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/445818/

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to move a normal (event horizon) singularity artificially? Assuming energy wasn't a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to not talk about gravitational singularities because I expect quantum gravity theory to prevent them.

In principle, you can move a black hole by gravitational attraction. Just drag a massive object past it, eg a neutron star. One way to do *that* is to set off a supernova of the appropriate size in the vicinity in such a way that the supernova remnant goes where you want it to. Figuring out how to do that safely & predictably is left as an exercise for the reader. ;)

And if it's an electrically charged black hole you can use electrostatic attraction; if it's uncharged, just throw a bunch of charged particles at it first to charge it up. But you'll need to work fairly quickly because charged black holes probably don't hold their charge for long.